# How to Forward Domain Name to Existing URL - .htaccess, DNS records, what else?

Tags: .htaccess, dns, forwarding, mx-record, a-records

I am much more of a programmer than a server guru so any help is much appreciated!

Forwarding a domain name for SEO reasons ->
NewDomain.com hosted with 3rd party needs to point to currently hosted site CurrentDomain.com.  I know I need to...

1)  Adjust NewDomain.com DNS A records specifically

- www.
- @.
- *.
- ftp.
- mail.

2)  Adjust NewDomain.com DNS MX records

3)  Add 301 Redirect to .htaccess file hosted at CurrentDomain.com so all requests for NewDomain will be forwarded to CurrentDomain.com.

`RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} NewDomain.com$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://CurrentDomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

**THE QUESTIONS:**
What else needs to be done?
1)  Is something missing?
2)  Should additional DNS changes be made?  If so, where?
3)  Should MX record point to mail.CurrentDomain.com if I don't want mail to NewDomain?
4)  Is there a better .htaccess file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your .htaccess is almost right, just minor corrections:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# for http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?newdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://CurrentDomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# for https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?newdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://CurrentDomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That way `newdomain.com` or `www.newdomain.com` will both be redirected with 301 to the browsers.

`[NC]` flag is for ignore case matching of host